# When I install express-validator I get file:express-validator

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I have used npm install express-validator, I checked my spelling 100 times, but whenever I install (I even deleted and reinstalled over and over again), on the dependencies from package.json, I keep getting "express-validator": "file:express-validator".

I get this kind of error

```
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please 
install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least 
constantinople 3.1.1
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN passport-practice@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN passport-practice@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Other modules are successfully installed

```
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
"constantinople": "^3.1.2",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"express-validator": "file:express-validator",
"jstransformer": "^1.0.0",
"mongoose": "^5.0.17",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-http": "^0.3.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"pug": "^2.0.3",
"validator": "^10.1.0"
```

Comment: Which is your `node` version?  Make sure that you have `Node.js 6` or newer in order to use it.

Comment: I had to specify the version ^5.2.0 or it would never let me download, keeps giving me deprecated error,

Answer (score 0):

removes it globally

```
 npm -g uninstall <name> --save
```